# Compile GWT project without source code available

Tags: java, gwt

Is it possible to compile a GWT project with a inherit module that I don't have the source code available? 
I have the JAR file containing the inherited module classes in my classpath.

Comment: I have only the compiled classes, but not the source code. When I compile the project I got the error: "No source code is available for type ...; did you forget to inherit a required module?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, GWT works on Java **sources** only, not classes.

Comment: Though it also needs the classes to be available as well - one of the early stages of the compiler uses the compiled bytecode to get information about classes, fields, and methods on the source path.

Comment: Won't the GWT compiler build these itself if it needs them?  If you remove the javac task from a GWT build.xml, the project still builds okay.  I thought the javac was simply there as an early-warning sanity check, to fail quickly if your code won't compile.

Comment: In my quick testing, no, not for actually compiling, but it may work for dev mode.

Comment: DevMode will compile all classes on the fly.  SuperDevMode doesn't require classes on classpath, (unless you use annotations which reference other classes, which is a known bug that will go away eventually).  I can attest that the compile process does NOT run a plain javac; instead, it translates source into pseudo-classes using eclipse JDT.  It only depends on classes to provide runtime information about a given class, though the comments in the code suggest this is to be removed to run wholly from source.

Answer (score 0):

If the libraries you are referencing are popular / open source libs, then you can use the gwt-maven-plugin from codehaus to automatically download and supply the source jars at compile time for you.

http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html

The parameter you are looking for is compileSourcesArtifacts.

If you can expand on the exact libs you are trying to use (whether they are proprietary or open source), I can give you better feedback about how to use the gwt-maven-plugin to bypass the need to have source on the classpath.